# How to implement tensorflow Estimator with multiple models for GAN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I used to work with tensorflow and then found Keras. It's easy to train multiple models in Keras using API like

```
for i in range(nb_batches):
    model1.train_on_batch(x, y)
    model2.train_on_batch(x, y)
```

Now I need to turn back to tensorflow for its high flexibility. The problem is there is no model in tensorflow, and it seems `Estimator` is something like model in Keras. However, `Estimator` API only provides a `model_fn` and a parameter arguments, which seems restricted us using only one `model_fn`.

I'm wondering if we can implement `Estimator` such that we can use some syntax like:

```
for i in range(nb_batches):
    ...
    my_estimator.partial_fit(x, y, MODEL='gen')
    ...
    my_estimator.partial_fit(x, y, MODEL='cri')
```

Comment: What kind of flexibility do you need? Keras is getting more and more flexible...